# Use CUPS with Chip Print Authentication

Tags: printing, authentication, raspberrypi, cups-lpd

I have a Raspberry with CUPS installed. Before printing a print job, I want the user to authenticate via a chip directly on the Raspberry via the built-in chip reader before printing.
I have not found anything on the internet.

Is that possible?

Thank you!

Comment: This is an interesting question, however I don't think it's really directly related to ubuntu. You will probably have better luck on a rPi or cups forum. However I am a big RPi fan and will help if I can. Some more details would be helpful... What is your printing setup? is the printer connected to the pi? are you network printing? what is this built in chip reader you speak of?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer!

The printer connects directly to a second-generation Raspberry via USB. The original plan was to print via a WiFi stick (also connected via USB) mobile (iOS and Android) and with laptops. (Win 10).
The printers are only connected via USB and not over the network.
That works so far ..

The chip reader is an additional device that I can connect directly to the Raspberry.
I have  a chip and a chip-card, these can be programmed.
rfid-kit RC522 is the name (when you Google it you can find it)
Do you need more information?

Thank you!